# How to distribute multiple versions of my app?

Tags: ios, distribution, testflight

I want to distribute two versions of my app, the stable branch as well as the current development trunk, using [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com). And, if possible, I want to invite the testers only once.

Can I have two versions of one app in one TestFlight team? Or maybe two app with different namens? Or can I create a second team and link it to the first one or copy the testers over?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately I think there is no nice way to do that. Your options are:

- Two different TestFlight teams. You'll have to invite people to both teams. But, TestFlight is clever and if it already knows about a user in another team who is in the provisioning profile in the IPA you upload, then you select that they can access the build, it will auto-invite the user.
- Use different app IDs for your stable and development branches.

I would personally go for the first option.

Comment: Let me get this straight: The second option means I could change the App id of one branch, by creating the app id in the provisioning portal and changing it in the xcode project. This second App could then be uploaded to the existing team and the testers can choose which one they want to install?

Comment: Yeh, pretty sure that would work. The first option is better IMO though.

Comment: This is a bad approach as another app identifier requires separate provisioning profiles etc. You'd then have to change bunch of stuff to make the different builds. Testflight grouping on app identifier is the worst descision ever...

Comment: @esbenr Agreed. This is a problem with HockeyApp as well. I wish it didn't do this :-(.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. TestFlight now lets you distribute and test multiple builds at the same time, so testers can choose from a number of builds to test.

Tap on build in test flight(mobile app) and you can see an option i.e. -**Previous Builds**

**First:**
[image]

===================================================================

**Second Step:**

[image]

=======================================================================================

**Third:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar requirement for our apps, where we need to send different beta versions of our apps to different user groups via TestFlight.

Creating a TestFlight team for each app will work, but here's a less messy way to do it:

1. Create a TestFlight Team *for each development team you're in*, not for each app. E.g. one for the apps you make in your day job, one for your the apps you make as personal side projects.
2. In each team, create a *Distribution List* for each individual app: Sign in to TestFlight, click on the **People** tab, then click on **+ Add Distribution List** (button in the top right)
3. Name the team according to the app
4. Select the testers who should be able to see the app
5. After you then upload a build, under **Teammates In The Provisioning Profile**, you'll see a list of the Distribution Lists you created. Click on the appropriate one for the build you just uploaded, and TestFlight will only tick those users.

This works in tandem with apps provisioned using the *iOS Team Provisioning Profile* (the one managed by Xcode, which ensures sure that all the devices on the Apple Developer Portal can install your apps).

[It also looks like TestFlight will allow you to ship the builds from different development branches of your app](https://twitter.com/testflightapp/status/209749311863529472), but it'll still be helpful to manage different apps with Distribution Lists rather than Teams.

Answer (score 0):

Update since April 2017 it is possible to distribute multiple versions: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04112017a